# GCM Unauthorized with PHP AppEngine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, unauthorized

I'm using the Appengine and rode a test script to send a message via GCM, but it turns the 401 Unauthorized error.

Follow my script

```
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$serverApiKey = "AIzaSyCKPMazvtdyhqhH7IdIqdHjqUtLNlHnsgA"; // API KEY SERVER
$reg = "APA91bEmal_3NpDSV5vuIysMjF8GYxO70_2Nmzx78VCSLmGpX_oX73TqfHczzjP_PgUmwYcdGz0yPGAajRLb1eP7wfzqtoADMzL1-DoCLYH9kz2dKknwcd7fZFSg_qM6Cgk_gphIRWD2FbcJZ83-ymnF1UhF40j32vYzD7WCDZnq_0-87R5Dbmk"; // registration id

$headers = array(
'Content-Type:application/json',
'Authorization:key=' . $serverApiKey
);

$data = array(
'registration_ids' => array($reg),
'data' => array(
'message' => 'Hello, World!'
));

print (json_encode($data) . "\n\n");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print ($response);
```

If I do the same test on my local machine, it works, but at appengine does not work

http://s3.postimg.org/ndzcfujoj/local_machine_1.png

http://s17.postimg.org/f48alja3z/local_machine_2.png

...in appengine not work

```
{"registration_ids":["APA91bEmal_3NpDSV5vuIysMjF8GYxO70_2Nmzx78VCSLmGpX_oX73TqfHczzjP_PgUmwYcdGz0yPGAajRLb1eP7wfzqtoADMzL1-DoCLYH9kz2dKknwcd7fZFSg_qM6Cgk_gphIRWD2FbcJZ83-ymnF1UhF40j32vYzD7WCDZnq_0-87R5Dbmk"],"data":{"message":"Hello, World!"}}
Unauthorized
Error 401
```

follows the API settings

```
Key for server applications
API key
AIzaSyCKPMazvtdyhqhH7IdIqdHjqUtLNlHnsgA
IPs
Any IP allowed
Activation date
Mar 12, 2015, 2:40:00 AM
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try using browser key.
Server key works from public ip adress.
Also you should white list your IP Address.

Comment: created the browser API, but it happened the same problem...

Here the key browser API....

Key for browser applications
API key
AIzaSyBDLrlKSotjkf0u46veF_Y8JfOx0nTZIVU
Referers
Any referer allowed
Activation date
Mar 12, 2015, 4:58:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for what reason the cURL does not work. I did it another way and it worked

```
$regId = "myid";
    $message = "Hello World!";


    $registrationIds = array($regId); 
    $msg = array( 'message' => $message, 'title' => 'notification center', 'tickerText' => $message, 'vibrate' => 1, 'sound' => 1, );

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
        'data' => $msg
    );
    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    $arrContextOptions=array(
        "http" => array(
            "method" => "POST",
            "header" =>
                'Authorization: key = MyApiKey'. "\r\n" .
                'Content-Type: application/json'. "\r\n",
            "content" => $fields,
        ),
        "ssl"=>array(
            "allow_self_signed"=>true,
            "verify_peer"=>false,
        ),
    );
    $arrContextOptions = stream_context_create($arrContextOptions);
    $result = file_get_contents('https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send', false, $arrContextOptions);

    echo $result;
```